# Adding and removing classes

Tags: jquery

I have a `jQuery` Credit Card Plugin and when you enter the credit card number it switches out a class that shows an image for the credit card entered.

How to I clear the credit card each time for the new one to appear?

```
<div>
    <form>
        <div id="ccc" class="form-group add-on">
            <label for="ccnumber">Credit card Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="credit-card" placeholder="Credit Card Number">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="c-card-type"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
if(cardType == null){
        return;
      }else{
        switch(cardType.name){
          case 'visa':
            $('#output').html('This Card is visa');  
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card vs'); 
            break;
          case 'mastercard':
            $('#output').html('This Card is mastercard');  
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card mc'); 
            break;
          case 'ax':
            $('#output').html('This Card is ax');  
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card ax'); 
            break;
          default:
            $('#output').html('We dont support ' + cardType.name);  
        }
      }
```

Comment: This problem is ambiguous to me. can you please provide full html and js code for better understanding? I am not getting any img that you mention in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From your code toggleClass will not work alone, please see the below example of toggleClass

```
<div id='mydiv' class="class1"></div>
$('#mydiv').toggleClass('class1 class2');
output: <div id='mydiv' class="class2"></div>
```

So you need to remove or empty the class attribute before the if statement or add to each case.

```
   $('#c-card-type').attr('class','');
or
  $('#c-card-type').removeAttr('class');
```

now your code should be

```
$('#c-card-type').attr('class','');
if(cardType == null){
        return;
      }else{
        switch(cardType.name){
          case 'visa':
            $('#output').html('This Card is visa');
          //  $('#c-card-type').attr('class','');
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card vs'); 
            break;
          case 'mastercard':
            $('#output').html('This Card is mastercard');  
          //  $('#c-card-type').attr('class','');
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card mc'); 
            break;
          case 'ax':
            $('#output').html('This Card is ax');  
          //   $('#c-card-type').attr('class','');
            $('#c-card-type').toggleClass('c-card ax'); 
            break;
          default:
            $('#output').html('We dont support ' + cardType.name);  
        }
      }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I got removeAttribute() not a function so I used removeAttr()

Answer (score 0):

You can use addClass and removeClass for this purpose

on a card type ex:visa,add visa class and remove other card classes.

```
   var cardTypeObj= $('#c-card-type');
   if(cardType == null){
        return;
      }else{
          cardTypeObj.addClass('c-card') 
        switch(cardType.name){
          case 'visa':
            $('#output').html('This Card is visa');  
            cardTypeObj.addClass('vs'); 
             cardTypeObj.removeClass('mc ax');
            break;
          case 'mastercard':
            $('#output').html('This Card is mastercard');  
            cardTypeObj.addClass('mc').removeClass('vs ax');
            break;
          case 'ax':
            $('#output').html('This Card is ax');  
          cardTypeObj.addClass('ax').removeClass('mc vs');
            break;
          default:
            $('#output').html('We dont support ' + cardType.name);  
        }
      }
```

Hope this helps